# Map an ImageView pixel position to screen position

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview

I have an image inside an ImageView and an external process is providing me the image relative position where I should place an other View. For instance on the position 300,125 of the image I should place a view and do some stuff with the second view like animating or capturing events.

How can I map the the provided image pixel position so I can place the second view on top of the first ImageView?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've managed using the method myImage.getImageMatrix().mapPoints(xy), but if I retrieve the getImageMatrix() in the onResume o onCreate I just get the identity matrix, where I'm supposed to retrieve it?

Comment: I've already tried with ViewTreeObserver, but I don't know which listener I should use. For instance I used the OnDrawListener and it was never executed. Or the OnWindowAttachListener that was executed when the matrix view was not ready (returning just an identity matrix)

Comment: `OnGlobalLayoutListener` does not work, for now I'm using `view.postDelayed` with a delay of 200 ms, but it looks a little bit hacky to me